# Get href and use as identifier jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am trying to implement a `hover` effect for an image map. I swap the image on hover, the replcement image have that section of the map filled with a 'hover' color.

```
<map name="Map">
    <area id="france" shape="poly" coords="98,133,123,129,151,116,165,129,188,140,181,156,175,167,177,176,181,195,171,203,153,201,145,209,110,196,119,171,110,149,94,141" href="/page/france">
    <area id="england" shape="poly" coords="94,119,114,115,139,116,150,100,130,69,117,75,119,89,115,106" href="/page/england">
    <area id="wales" shape="poly" coords="118,87,112,107,99,100,109,86" href="/page/wales">
    // many more areas //
</map>
```

jQuery

```
$('#england').hover(
    function() {
        $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map-en.gif');
    },
    function() {
        $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map.gif');
    }
);
```

It works very nicely. The problem is I have many areas within my image map. Is there a way with jQuery of getting the last part of the href from a link and putting it into a dynamic working variable?

**Example logic:**

```
var identifier = area/href/this

$(identifier).hover(
        function() {
            $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map-'+identifier+'.gif');
        },
        function() {
            $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map.gif');
        }
    );
```

Comment: Little lost in the question, last part of which `href`?

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for reply,  i mean extract the last part as in `england` from href `/page/england`

Comment: How about `var href = this.href.split("/page/")[0];`

Comment: @theApptracker `this.id` would give you that too.

Comment: @tymeJV That's a really good idea, i'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$('area').hover(function(){
      $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map-'+this.href.split('/').pop().slice(0,2) +'.gif');
}, function(){
      $('img').attr('src', '/lib/img/layout/map.gif');
});
```

`this.href.split('/').pop().slice(0,2)` takes the first 2 characters of the last token of the href of the hovered area. You could also give to your areas more normalized identifiants (like "en", "fr") so you wouldn't have to do this extraction.

Comment: I can change the id's as you advise as currently I only have id's for the first three. Is there any way I could do this without id's and instead use the last part of the href? Otherwise i think this is the best solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheApptracker Yes, use this.href.split('/').pop() instead of this.id

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of **dystroy** and answering your doubt about getting only the end of the href you can use string split:

```
$("#france").attr('href').split("/")[2]
```

The **[2]** is to get the result that is the land name (in the example: *france*)

Instead of using the **2** you can also first store in a variable and then get the last item using length:

```
var tmp = $('#france').attr('href').split("/");

tmp[tmp.length-1];
```

It will print the last item of the href always. In this case "france"